# Display of div/section in different ways

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a html page with a requirement to show multiple sections. example: employees, their roles, and departments they belong to etc.

I want to have the flexibility of displaying each sections either as an accordian, tabs or any other possible view. Is there a framework/way to make the UI look a specific way either using css/javascript etc.

Comment: You can use the jQuery UI widgets: http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: how can i change the display from accordian to tabs of the same div/section using these widgeds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularjs. Angular has the concept of MVC framework on client side : https://angularjs.org/

This link can help you: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: thanks for your reply, this is something which i am very much interested in, do you have any demo link for me to look and have a play around?